# Opening txt file in a label in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm trying to open a `.txt` file in a label with Tkinter, using Python 3.x
This is the code I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

#Title
tk.title("My Program")


f = open("file.txt", "r", encoding="UTF8").readlines()
Label(tk, text=f) .grid(row=0)

tk.mainloop()
```

It works, and this is what I get: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPIaG.png)

How can I visualize the text without parenthesis? And how can I align/justify it?

Comment: The brackets are there because `.readlines()` returns a list.  You can use `f = ''.join(f)` to get rid of them.  As far as align and justifying goes, I'd suggest reading the docs or [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

Comment: Or he could simply use `read()` instead of `readlines()`.

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Yeah that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly braces are there because you told the label to display a list rather than a string. The reason is due to the fact that Tkinter is built on top of a tcl interpreter, and tcl uses curly braces to preserver the list element boundaries.

The simple solution is to explicitly convert your list to a string, or simply not use a list:

### Convert the list to a string:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r", encoding="UTF8").readlines()
Label(tk, text="\n".join(f)) .grid(row=0)
```

### insert the raw, non-list data:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r", encoding="UTF8").read()
Label(tk, text=f) .grid(row=0)
```